# datetime instead of str in read_excell with pandas

Tags: string, pandas, datetime

I have a dataset saved in an xls file.
In this dataset there are 4 columns that represent dates, in the format dd/mm/yyyy.
My problem is that when I read it in python using pandas and the function read_excel all the columns are read as string, except one, read as datetime64[ns], also if I specify dtypes={column=str}. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dates in Excel are frequently stored as numbers, which allows you to do things like subtract them, even though they might be displayed as human-readable dates like dd/mm/yyyy. Pandas is handily taking those numbers and interpreting them as dates, which lets you deal with them more flexibly.

To turn them into strings, you can use the `converters` argument of `pd.read_excel` like so:

```py
df = pd.read_excel(filename, converters={'name_of_date_column': lambda dt: dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')})
```

The [strftime](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior) method lets you format dates however you like. Specifying a converter for your column lets you apply the function to the data as you read it in.